# How to open a link in a specified, open window

Tags: javascript, html

I have this web application which has integrations into other webapps like `Salesforce`.

Now I have a link in `Salesforce` which opens a new window of my application, but I would like it to open the link inside the window, where my webapp is already open.

Scenario:

- tab1: mywebapp, tab2: salesforce
- click link in tab2: link opens in tab3 (link should open in tab1)

I've looked into `target` attribute of links, but they only target named frames and I'm not sure how I could name `tab1` to be a valid target.

Any other hints people can give me?

Edit:

`tab1` already exists, so I can't actually do the 'open a new window with a name' thing. I'd somehow have to either make `tab1` have a name through code (tab1 is opened via URL)

Comment: can you post this part of code ?

Comment: If you give a link a target attribute to open in a new window that will give that new window/tab that name. As long as you always refer to the same name in your links the browser should change the location of that tab/window.

Comment: @BrianShamblen, yeah I know that. But in this case the window I want to use already exists and is opened from an URL

Comment: @ProllyGeek I'm not sure what part you are referring to? Currently I have a named target which opens into a new window, but then opens into the same window each subsequent click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a name to the window you opend.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'mywin'); return false;">Click here to open window first</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', 'mywin'); return false;">Open link in specific window</a>
```

**Edit**

You can name a window (or tab) on **some** browsers.

```
<script>
    this.name = "mywin";
</script>
```

And open a link to the tab.

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="mywin">Open link in specific window</a>
```

It works on IE, but not Chrome...

Comment: Lovely solution if only I could open `tab1` this way. Too bad `tab1` is already opened via URL.

Comment: Please, in `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'mywin'); return false;">Click here to open window first</a>` , mywin name is given to the new window because there wasnt such a window name.But in `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', 'mywin'); return false;">Open link in specific window</a>` , the newly created window is opened in mywin window because it exists already.Is it true?